# Select nan column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I want to select a nan column which is the one circled blue? It is a second column in the picture. Or Is there any ways to filter the value in row number 12 in the second column?
  [this is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3GUC.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried data[data.columns[1]] but it is not working

Comment: Try to index with `.iloc`:  `df.iloc[:, 1]`

Comment: Yo bro. It works :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can select the entire column just by typing `data['nan']`.

For selecting the 12th row in this column, use `data.iloc[12].nan`.

Comment: Nah it ain't working. The method of @ALollz above is correct!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to select the nan column you can try replacing the nan column name and then go for pd.dropna() or pd.fillna() based on your requirment.